# Numpy print floats <1 without the leading 0

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I need to display and inspect large numpy matrices of floats in the interval `[0,1]` and am trying to avoid line wrapping, so each printed value should be as short as possible.  I'm already using `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)` which yields something like

```
[[1.   0.93 0.87 0.9  0.9  1.   0.93 1.   0.9  0.97 0.97 0.97 0.77 0.73 0.73 0.83 0.67 0.87 0.8  0.87 0.9  0.8  0.9  0.97 0.97 0.83 0.57]
 [0.93 1.   0.83 0.8  0.83 0.9  0.97 0.9  0.97 0.97 0.97 0.87 0.73 0.67 0.63 0.77 0.6  0.8  0.7  0.9  0.9  0.8  0.83 0.97 0.97 0.73 0.53]
 [0.87 0.83 1.   0.7  0.73 0.9  0.8  0.93 0.8  0.83 0.9  0.77 0.67 0.7  0.67 0.67 0.6  0.73 0.63 0.7  0.73 0.77 0.87 0.93 0.83 0.63 0.5 ]
...
]
```

Since all of the float values are `<=1`, I could save a character per column by getting rid of leading `0`s and hence view larger mats on my screen.  E.g. `0.87` -> `.87`.  **How do I do this?**

I don't care what happens to the `1.`.  It could stay the same (and have misaligned `.` with the other numbers), or be displayed as `1`.  Similar for `0.`.  It can stay `0.` or be `0`.  I also don't care what the solution does if the matrix happens to contain values outside of `[0,1]`.

I have looked through [numpy.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) and [numpy.format_float_positional](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html), but they can't do this.  Googling "numpy skip leading 0 for floats" merely brings up a lot of solutions for single floats non-numpy contexts (e.g. `printf("%0.2f", val)[1:]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':lambda n: f"{n:.2f}".replace("0.",".")})
```

Note: this is suggested for the specific circumstances of the question asked (such as values < 1). This may not be a good solution outside of the scope of this question.

Edit by OP: Question has been clarified that values are `<=1`, so the solution needs to instead be

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float':lambda n: f"{n:.2f}".replace("0.",".")}).replace(".00", "  ")
```

Since the `{n:.2f}` formatter will display `1.` as `1.00`, it needs to be replaced with `" "` (2 spaces), so that the col is only 3 characters.  This also handles `0` since the former solution would display it as `0.00`.

Comment: The OP said "Since all of the float values are <1".

Comment: Hmm You are right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to direct the formatted output to a string and replace all occurrences of `0.` with `.`, and `1.`  with `1` .

Comment: Could you add an example of how this is done in numpy?  Is it really just `str(mat).replace('0.', '.').replace('1.', '1')`?

Comment: @waldol1 I don' know if `str(mat)` gives the formatting that you want. That's up to you.